# Illegal Argument exception while connecting to Google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-shared-drive

In the following code I'm trying to upload an image taken by the camera to Google Drive.
I have not used the account picker to pick the account name but I'm passing the account name through the program itself. 
I'm calling a handleCamera to start camera and capture image and save2Drive() to upload it to GoogleDrive. 
The code is

```
public class first extends Activity {

      static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 3;

      private static Uri fileUri = null;
      private static Drive service = null;
      private GoogleAccountCredential credential = null;
      String accountName = "blogmsr28@gmail.com";


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.firstscreen);
    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Arrays.asList(new String[]{DriveScopes.DRIVE}));
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
    service = getDriveService(credential);
    showToast(" Inside oncreate");
    handleCamera();
    save2Drive();

  }


  public void handleCamera(){

                String mediaStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath();
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
                fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(mediaStorageDir + java.io.File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg"));

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
  }


  public void save2Drive() {

      Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            try {

              java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
              FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", fileContent);


              File body = new File();
              body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
              body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");

              File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).setOcr(true).execute();

              if (file != null) {
                showToast("Photo uploaded: " + file.getTitle());

              }
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        });
        t.start();


  }
private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential)
            .build();
      }

      public void showToast(final String toast) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
            });
      }

}
```

The stack trace is

```
05-10 14:48:53.074: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(17592): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11750
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592): Process: com.example.drivequickstart, PID: 17592
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1624)
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.o$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:255)
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:279)
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592):    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:858)
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:559)
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithBackOffAndGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:581)
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeUploadInitiation(MediaHttpUploader.java:533)
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:393)
05-10 14:48:53.148: E/AndroidRuntime(17592):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:345)
```

Answer (score 1):

You getting error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null

because drive api client library required `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission.You need to have that permission in your manifest and request it at runtime, as appropriate.﻿

Comment: Ok..I'll try that.